# How i can put values to text input?

Tags: javascript, prototype

I have an input:

```
<input type="text" value="value" id="textinput" />
```

and a picture:

```
<img src="folan.png" value="hi" id="hi" />
```

I want that when I click the image it adds text to the input value.
How I can accomplish this with PrototypeJS or pure JavaScript?

I tried this code:

```
document.getElementById("hi").addEventListener('click', function () {
    var text = document.getElementById('textinput');
    text.text = (text.text + ' after clicking');
});
```

Comment: Can you share the code of your attempts so far?

Comment: What is this? `'ar text = '` Why is that being passed instead of the ID?

Comment: I correct @cookiemonster.

Comment: You should be easily able to find answers to these most basic questions if you'd search.

Comment: No @cookiemonster , I wanna add a text to input field.that's not. I search but i'm not find.

Comment: No what? How is setting its `.value` not what you want? If that doesn't do it, then I have no idea what you're asking.

Comment: People who upvote questions like this should be banned for life.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're trying to do here:

```
var text = document.getElementById('ar text = ');
```

But `ar text =` isn't an element's `id`.  Maybe you meant this?:

```
var text = document.getElementById('textinput');
```

Additionally, you don't want to set the `text` property on an `input` element, you want to set its `value`:

```
text.value = (text.value + ' after clicking');
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/FCcpM/)